# What do the 'n', 'p', and 'u' stand for that follow Google Benchmark's perf counter results?

Tags: perf, google-benchmark

I have a Google Benchmark such as the following.

```
#include "benchmark/benchmark.h"
#include <cstring>

static void bench_memset(benchmark::State& state) {
    char buffer[16];

    for(auto _ : state) {
        memset(buffer, '\0', 16);
        benchmark::ClobberMemory();
    }
}

BENCHMARK(bench_memset);
BENCHMARK_MAIN();
```

And I run it with the following command.

```
./my_benchmark --benchmark_perf_counters=BRANCH-MISSES,CACHE-MISSES,CACHE-REFERENCES --benchmark_counters_tabular=true
```

Which results in the following data.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark             Time             CPU   Iterations BRANCH-MISSES CACHE-MISSES CACHE-REFERENCES
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bench_memset      0.611 ns        0.611 ns   1000000000            7n        1000p              52n
```

I generally understand the concept of branch and cache misses, but I don't understand the meaning of the 'n' and 'p' that are printed after the perf counter metrics.

I searched both [Google Benchmark's documentation](https://github.com/google/benchmark/blob/main/docs/user_guide.md) and [Perf's documentation](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Tutorial), but neither seem to mention this.

I also notice that if I bump up the size of my workload,

```
static void bench_memset(benchmark::State& state) {
    char buffer[4096];

    for(auto _ : state) {
        memset(buffer, '\0', 4096);
        benchmark::ClobberMemory();
    }
}
```

Then the 'n' will change to 'u', which is also mysterious.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Benchmark             Time             CPU   Iterations BRANCH-MISSES CACHE-MISSES CACHE-REFERENCES
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
bench_memset       96.0 ns         96.0 ns      6959398      1.14952u            0         81.6163u
```

I've also noticed with other benchmarks that there may be no letter at all.

What do these letters stand for?

Comment: BTW, `memset(buffer, '\0', 16);` should compile to one `movups` store (of an XMM register that was zeroed outside the loop), which will normally hit in cache since it's the same buffer every time. (And not touch L3, only L1d, if that's what "cache-references" counts).  I'm surprised it runs so slowly; I'd expect 1 iteration per clock cycle, so like 0.25 ns on a 4GHz CPU.  Maybe there's more loop overhead for checking the keep-running status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--benchmark_perf_counters` lists additional perf counters to collect, in libpfm format. Thus, the information about `u`, `p` and `n` can be found in the manual of the perfmon2 project. It shows hardware counters, and Benchmarks outputs fractions of an overall test duration:

- p - pico-, 10<sup>−12</sup>, 1000p of 1000000000 is 1 cache miss of 1e9 iterations.
- n - nano-, 10<sup>−9</sup>, 7n of 1000000000 is 7 branch prediction misses of 1e9 iterations.
- u - micro-, 10<sup>−6</sup>, 81.6163u of 6959398 is 568 cache references of 6959398 iterations.

In other words, these values are probabilities.

IMHO It would be better if they show just counters, fractions could be easy computed like 7 / 1e9 or 568 / 6959398.

Comment: It's using those metric prefixes on things other than times.  Like 7 nano (branch-mispredicts) per benchmark iteration?  So, 7 branch mispredicts over the whole run of 1000000000 = 1e9 iterations, that sounds plausible.  And 1000p cache misses looks extremely weird, but switching to the next smaller unit at what would have been 1 nano cache-miss = 1000 pico cache-misses makes some sense.

Comment: `1000p` is 1e-9, that means one cache miss, at first iteration of all 10e9, is good. Am I mistaken with fractions of seconds, are they fractions of a test duration?

Comment: Correct, that's what I said.  That looks normal.  But your answer only talks about seconds, not other units those metric prefixes can apply to.  I was trying to point out that you should make more of a point of saying that seconds is just one example of a unit.  Your answer implies that `7n` means 7 nanoseconds.  But no, that would be 7 ns, prefix + unit.  `7n` doesn't include a unit because it's dimensionless, 7 nano-counts of the thing in this column (per iteration, just like how the 0.61 ns time is per iteration)